# proof of: $\gcd(n^a - 1, n^b - 1) = n^{\gcd(a,b)}- 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I have a problem with following proof:

$$\gcd(n^a - 1, n^b-1) = n^{\gcd(a,b)} - 1 $$

The only thing that I can show is fact:
$$n^{\gcd(a,b)} -1 | n^a - 1$$
$$n^{\gcd(a,b)} -1 | n^b - 1$$
And $k={\gcd(a,b)} $ is the biggest number that $n^k-1 | n^a - 1$ and $n^k-1|n^b-1$
But how to show that $n^{\gcd(a,b)}-1$ is $\ the\ biggest\ $ divisor or alternatively that every divisor is form $n^k-1$?

Comment: flag a post as duplicate is not useful. It may have new solution that could benefit the OP or other members. This (MSE) is about finding a creative solution to a question and not about finding whether the question has been posted before by someone else.